# Java: grouping together multiple Lists to one list

Tags: java, average, java-8

Is there a quick way to take a `List< List<Double> >` and average them so I only have one Double list where each column is the average of all the original lists at that column?

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: Yep, I probably should have mentioned that earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Java 8 you can write something like this - it is not really short though...

```
List<List<Double>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1d, 2d, 3d),
                                        Arrays.asList(2d, 3d, 4d, 5d));

//the largest list size
int maxSize = list.stream().mapToInt(List::size).max().orElse(0);

//for each index in the final list, we calculate the average across "valid" lists
//i.e. lists that are large enough
List<Double> averages = IntStream.range(0, maxSize)
                        .mapToObj(i -> list.stream()
                                            .filter(sublist -> sublist.size() > i)
                                            .mapToDouble(sublist -> sublist.get(i))
                                            .average().getAsDouble())
                        .collect(toList());

//prints averages = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 5.0]
System.out.println("averages = " + averages);
```

Comment: That's not how I understood the question. I thought the OP wanted output of [1.5 2.5 3.5] for your input.

Comment: I'm sorry I think you have the wrong idea. What I want is, for example, column 3 of all of the lists to be averaged into column 3 of averages.

Comment: You can replace `mapToDouble(…).boxed()` with `mapToObj(…)` on the outer stream.